# Who are the Elders in the beginning of Avot

Tags: rabbis, mesorah-tradition, pirke-avot-ethicsof, kedusha-holiness

The [Pirkei Avot 1:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.1.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) says

> משֶׁה קִבֵּל תּוֹרָה מִסִּינַי, וּמְסָרָהּ לִיהוֹשֻׁעַ, **וִיהוֹשֻׁעַ
> לִזְקֵנִים, וּזְקֵנִים לִנְבִיאִים**,
> וּנְבִיאִים מְסָרוּהָ לְאַנְשֵׁי כְנֶסֶת הַגְּדוֹלָה.
>
> Moshe received the Torah from Sinai and transmitted it to Yehoshua, and Yehoshua to the Elders, and the Elders to the Prophets, and the Prophets transmitted it to the Men of the Great Assembly.

Who were the *Elders*? And how can we understand their spiritual abilities?

Comment: Why do you assume that they were great?

Comment: Those are two different questions. Please elaborate on what do you mean by greatness.

Comment: The leading Torah scholars of those generations were collectively called "The Elders".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good starting point is [Rabbeinu Yonah](https://www.sefaria.org/Rabbeinu_Yonah_on_Pirkei_Avot.1.1.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) who writes:

> ויהושע לזקנים - כמו שנאמר (יהושע כ"ד ל"א) וכל ימי הזקנים אשר האריכו ימים אחרי יהושע
>
> and Yehoshua to the Elders: As it is stated ([Joshua 24:31](https://www.sefaria.org/Joshua.24.31?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)), and all the days of the elders who had length of days after Joshua."

If one refers to the stated verse in Yehoshua over there it is worth noting the commentaries.

[Abarbanel](https://www.sefaria.org/Joshua.24.31?lang=bi&p2=Abarbanel_on_Joshua.24.31.1&lang2=bi) writes:

> וזכר שכל ימי יהושע וימי הזקנים שהאריכו ימים אחריו עבדו ישראל את ה', לפי שהזקנים היו מישרים לפניהם את הדרך יען וביען הם ידעו את כל מעשה ה', רוצה לומר שראו הנסים שנעשו להם
>
> And he remembered that all the days of Yehoshua and the days of the elders that were long after him, Israel served Hashem, since **the elders were lit. straightened the way (i.e. were upright and showed them how to behave) because they surely knew all the actions of Hashem, which means to say they saw the miracles that were performed for them.**

The [Metzudos Dovid](https://www.sefaria.org/Joshua.24.31?lang=bi&p2=Metzudat_David_on_Joshua.24.31.1&lang2=bi) says that these elders accordingly helped Klal Yisroel to direct their hearts more readily to Hashem i.e. **they helped the nation to be more dedicated in their service of G-d**.

Another function of the elders role is brought by Rashi who writes:

> ויהושע לזקנים - ולא רצה למסרה לשבעים זקנים שהיו בימי משה, אלא מסרה לזקנים שהיו רודים ושוטרים על ישראל
>
> And Yehoshua to the the elders - and he did not want to transmit it to the 70 elders that were in the days of Moshe, but rather **he gave it over to the elders that would discipline and police Israel**.

So they were there to act as the policemen and upholders of law to ensure that the nation remained on the "straight and narrow".

In terms of who they were, as has been mentioned already, a similar approach is employed by the [Bartenura](https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.1.1?lang=bi&p2=Bartenura_on_Pirkei_Avot.1.1.3&lang2=bi):

> לִזְקֵנִים. שֶׁהֶאֱרִיכוּ יָמִים אַחֲרֵי יְהוֹשֻׁעַ. וְאוֹתָם הַזְּקֵנִים לִזְקֵנִים אֲחֵרִים עַד שֶׁהִגִּיעוּ לִתְחִלָּתָם שֶׁל נְבִיאִים שֶׁהֵן עֵלִי הַכֹּהֵן וּשְׁמוּאֵל הָרָמָתִי
>
> To the elders: who lived long after Yehoshua, and those elders (passed it) to other elders until they reached the beginning of the prophets, who are **Eli the priest and Shmuel of Ramah**. (Refer to the other answer for more on this).

However, it is when we get to the Midrash in [Bamidbar Rabbah 3:7](https://www.sefaria.org/Bamidbar_Rabbah.3.7?lang=bi) we finally get two alternative definitions as to who this grouping of elders were, who historically probably were at the start of this "elders" chain:

> וַיַּעֲבֹד יִשְׂרָאֵל אֶת ה' כֹּל יְמֵי יְהוֹשֻׁעַ וגו', מִי הָיוּ הַזְּקֵנִים הַלָּלוּ, רַבִּי יְהוּדָה הַלֵּוִי בְּשֵׁם רַבּוֹתֵינוּ אָמַר אֵלּוּ הָיוּ בְּנֵי לֵוִי. רַבִּי בֶּרֶכְיָה בֶּן רַבִּי חֶלְבּוֹ בְּשֵׁם אַבָּא סְמוּקְיָד אֶלְדָד וּמֵידָד הָיוּ, נִמְצֵאתָ אוֹמֵר שֶׁהֶאֱרִיכוּ יָמִים אַחַר יְהוֹשֻׁעַ
>
> And Israel served Hashem all the days of Yehoshua etc - Who were these elders? Rabbi Yehuda HaLevi in the name of our Rabbis said these are the **children of Levi**. Rabbi Berechya the son of Rabbi Chelbo in the name of Abbah Semukyad (said) they were **Eldad and Meidad**, you are found to say that they extended days after Yehoshua.

Answer (score 5):

See mefarshim, e.g. Yachin:

> הן השופטים שאחר יהושע:‏
>
> The elders: The judges after Yehoshua.
>
> שעלי השופט האחרון מסר לשמואל ראש הנביאים.‏
>
> Eli (Hakohen), the last judge, transmitted to Shmuel, the first prophet.

What was their greatness? They were the leaders of the Israeli Nation.

Comment: The answer neither does explain their greatness

Answer (score 0):

As @kouty wrote, the last of the elders was Eli. This can be inferred from a number of sources, such as [Yalkut Shimoni on Nach 115:1](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Yalkut_Shimoni_on_Nach.115.1?vhe=Yalkut_Shimoni_on_Nach&lang=en):

> "עמדו זקנים ומסרוה לנביאים בעמידה. עמדו נביאים ומסרוה לדוד בעמידה."

Translation: "The elders stood and passed [the scroll with instructions for building the Temple] to the prophets standing. Stood the prophets and passed [the Torah] to David standing."

while another [midrash](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Otzar_Midrashim%2C_Various_%27Megilot%27%2C_Megillat_Beit_Hamikdash.4?vhe=Otzar_Midrashim,_New_York,_1915&lang=bi) states that David received this scroll from Shmuel. Therefore, the term "prophets" refers to Shmuel, and the term "elders" refers to Eli, who was Shmuel's teacher and on whom it says "Now Eli was very old".

(this and other explanations were brought in Ze'ev Ehrlich's essay "The Last of the Elders" ([אחרון הזקנים](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:f1gZB7NzbSYJ:www.herzog.ac.il/vtc/0034067.doc%20&cd=12&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=il))"

The elders' greatness was that they were wise ([Kiddushin 32b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Kiddushin.32b.8?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi)), and they were, well, elders - they were the elders of the tribes and evidently they were considered to be respected individuals (in [Bamidbar 11:16](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Numbers.11.16?lang=bi&aliyot=0) they are described as being *known* as the elders and the officers of the people"). It's possible that part of their greatness was that they were sages first and prophets second (see [Bava Batra 12a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Bava_Batra.12a.14?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi)).